# Transform an NSAttributedString to plain text

Tags: cocoa, nsattributedstring

I have an instance of `NSData` containing attributed text (`NSAttributedString`) originating from an `NSTextView`. I want to convert the attributed string to a plain string (`NSString`) without any formatting to do some text analysis (at the moment of conversion I do not have access to the originating NSTextView nor its NSTextStorage instance).

What would be the best way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Out of curiosity I examined the result of:

```
[[[self textView] textStorage] words]
```

which appeared to be a handy thing for doing some text analysis. The resulting array contains instances of NSSubTextStorage (example below of the word "Eastern"):

> Eastern{
>       NSFont = "\"LucidaGrande 11.00 pt. P [] (0x7ffcaae08330) fobj=0x10a8472d0, spc=3.48\"";
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null),
>   BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0.05,
>   HeaderLevel 0"; }

NSSubTextStorage is probably a private class as I could not find any documentation for it. It also retains all formatting.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have an `NSData`, say `data`, containing an encoded `NSAttributedString`. To reverse the process:

```
NSAttributedString *nas = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                           options:nil
                                                documentAttributes:NULL
                                                             error:NULL];
```

and to get the plain text without attributes you then do:

```
NSString *str = [nas string];
```

Comment: Oh my... I must go out for a bit of fresh air. Thanks for the answer! Can't believe I did not see that myself... [self kick]

Comment: If an image attachment exists in attributed screen, resultant string property will return a ? in that attachment's place. I'm trying to find solution for it. Can u please share if you have any idea?

Comment: @Avi - What you are probably seeing is the `NSAttachmentCharacter` and if so you can simply remove any occurrences of it. It's documented as part of `NSTextAttachment`.

Answer (score 32):

Updating for Swift 5:

```
attributedText.string
```

Answer (score 4):

With Swift 5 and macOS 10.0+, `NSAttributedString` has a property called [`string`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1412616-string). `string` has the following declaration:

```
var string: String { get }
```

> The character contents of the receiver as an `NSString` object.

Apple also states about `string`:

> Attachment characters are not removed from the value of this property. [...]

---

The following Playground code shows how to use `NSAttributedString`'s `string` property in order to retrieve the string content of an `NSAttributedString` instance:

```swift
import Cocoa

let string = "Some text"
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle : NSUnderlineStyle.single]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)

/* later */

let newString = attributedString.string
print(newString) // prints: "Some text"
print(type(of: newString)) // prints: String
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 5.7 (or maybe earlier), the new [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) struct no longer has a `string` property. The code below works, even looking silly.

```
part.characters.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "")
```