# How we converted NSAttributed String Backed to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata, nsattributedstring

I am changing the font of textview, after I get attributed string then I use to pass it to another controller which also shows me attributed string. I would like to convert attributed string to `NSString` (with specific font which I have changed).

I am using

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:text.attributedText];
NSAttributedString *nas = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                           options:nil
                                                documentAttributes:NULL
                                                             error:NULL];

NSString *str = [nas string];
```

Which shows below log:

```
2014-11-17 14:23:17.094 format[2785:98416] bplist00‘°¢T$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiver—TrootÄØ"    
%&'().6EFJRSTU[`glt}~ÅâäãåíñúU$null‘
XNSString\NSAttributesV$class_NSAttributeInfoÄÄÄ!ÄYThud high“
ZNS.objectsÄ¢ÄÄ”
 !WNS.keys£ÄÄ   ÄÄ£"#$ÄÄÄ[NSUnderline_NSParagraphStyleVNSFont”
*+,-(ZNSTabStops_NSWritingDirectionÄ
Ä
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018292/transform-an-nsattributedstring-to-plain-text

Answer (score 1):

Actually `NSAttributedString` has `string` property:

```
NSString *result = myAttributedString.string;
```

Comment: i am getting my string back but my text style became orginal i am needed change style of text.

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
[attributedString string];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert attributed string to string using following line of code :

```
self.txtView.text = [attributedstring string];
```

but I suggest its better use as attribute text like below :

```
self.txtView.attributedText = attributedstring;
```